# Access a private Docker registry via VPN from an Azure Kubernetes cluster

Tags: networking, vpn, kubernetes, aks

In my company's network we have a Sonatype Nexus instance used as a private registry of Docker images. Now we need to deploy those images to our AKS cluster (we already have one) but I don't know how to configure the AKS cluster in order to access the company's VPN and the Nexus instance.

Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I configured a new Azure Virtual Network, linked it to the company's VPN and used this one when creating the AKS cluster.

More details here
https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni